# Missed hotend's thoat depth during install, is it too bad?

Tags: hotend

I replaced my hotend's thoat and I made a mistake I hope it's not fatal for the new install. After reassembling the hotend I left a marging of about 5mm of the throat out of the heatsink. I noticed something was off when leveling the bed and then confirmed it after seeing more underextrusion artifacts than expected on a test print. I fixed it but now I'm worried about the debris left by the pocket made when I missed the throat depth (see pic below)

[image: throat misinstall]

The material used was PLA so that'll be most of the debris I guess. Is it that bad? I'm printing a second benchy right now which looks OK, but I'm worried about possible clogging in the future. This is an all-metal thoat, by the way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s probably fine.

If you have it tightened down all the way now, you’ve squished most of the plastic out. You might burn up some plastic if your block gets too hot, but you could easily do that anyway. You might also have some issues with cold pulling and cold-ish unloading, but I wouldn’t expect it.

If you’re worried, your only recourse is to remove the nozzle and clean it out, probably while hot. Q-tips work fairly well for that. Unless you’re doing something fancier than PLA though, I think you’ll be fine.